# HTML - Is there a way to set a Time limit for a Datetime-local element?

Tags: html

Is there a way to set a Time limit for a Datetime-local element. 
For example, being able to make a booking between the times of 8:00AM to 18:00 AM and to be able only to choose between that in a DateTime-local. Here is my HTML code as well, if it could help:

```
<h1 id="header">Bookings Creation</h1>
    <form action="booking.php" method="post">           
        First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" /><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" /> <br />
        Date And Time From: <input type="datetime-local" name="DateAndTimeFrom"/><br />
        Date And Time From: <input type="datetime-local" name="DateAndTimeTo"/><br />
        Booking Type: <select name="BookingType"> <br />
            <option value="0">Single</option>
            <option value="1">Group</option>
            <option value="2">Tournament</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I checked datetime-local doesn't work with such attributes, but
you can use `min` and `max` attributes of time input like that:

```
<input type="time" min="08:00:00" max="18:00:00"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now You can use `min` and `max` attributes to set limits for these input types as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
   name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
   min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00">
```